# Verifying credit card number with given criterion

Tags: python

I have been learning Python for a week and it's my first time to do some coding.
I am having this problem as the title said. What I wrote for rule#1 and rule#2 were okay, but for 3 and 4 it won't work.

The given criterion was:

> 1. if 1st digit =4 then passed or return 1 (violated 1st rule)
> 2. if 4th dig > 5th dig then passed or return 2 (violated 2nd rule)
> 3. The sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4 or return 3
> 4. if you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number and the seventh and eighth digits as a two-digit number, their sum must be 100 or return 4

like so:

```py
def verify(number) : # 
      x= int(number[0]+number[1]+number[2]+number[3])
      y= int(number[5]+number[6]+number[7]+number[8])
      z= int(number[11]+number[12]+number[13]+number[10])
      temp = int(x) + int(y) + int(z)
      temp2 = int(number[1]+number[0])
      temp3 = int(number[8]+number[7])
      sum1 = int(number[0])+int(number[1])+int(number[2])+int(number[3])+int(number[5])+int(number[6])+int(number[7])+int(number[8])+int(number[11])+int(number[10])+int(number[12])+int(number[13])

      sum2 = temp2 + temp3
      if int(number[0]) != 4:
          return 1
          #rule1
      elif int(number[3]) <= int(number[5]) and int(number[0]) == 4:
          return 2
          #rule2
      elif sum1 % 4 != 0 and number[3] > number[5] and number[0] == 4: 
          return 3
          #rule3
      elif sum1 % 4 == 0 and number[3] > number[5] and number[0] == 4 and sum2 != 100:
          return 4
          #rule4
      else:
          return True    

print("the entered credit number is","output")

input = "9000-0000-0000" #It can vary to test the code
output = verify(input)
```

sorry for my poor English ( I am not a native)

Comment: What’s wrong with the code?

Comment: if I input, for example, 4007-6000-000, I still get the return of true even though it violates rule #3

Answer (score 1):

How about you create a seperate function for the sum of all digits requirement, you have the first two requirements pretty much correct:

```
def verify(number_str):
    # if 1st digit = 4 then passed or return 1 (violated 1st rule) 
    if int(number_str[0]) != 4:
        return 1
    # if 4th dig > 5th dig then passed or return 2 (violated 2nd rule)
    elif int(number_str[3]) <= int(number_str[5]):
        return 2
    # the sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4 or return 3  (violated 3rd rule)
    elif get_sum_of_digits(number_str) % 4 != 0:
        return 3
    # if you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number and the seventh
    # and eighth digits as a two-digit number, their sum must be 100 or return 4
    elif int(number_str[0:2]) + int(number_str[7:9]) != 100:
        return 4
    # the number is valid otherwise
    return True

def get_sum_of_digits(number_str):
    total = 0
    for char in number_str:
        if char.isdigit(): # to ignore the `-` characters
            total += int(char)
    return total
```

---

**Example Invalid Usage 1:**

```
input_number  = "9000-0000-0000"
output = verify(input_number)
if isinstance(output, bool):
    print("The entered credit number is valid.")
else:
    print(f"The entered credit number is not valid. Error code: {output}")
```

**Output:**

```
The entered credit number is not valid. Error code: 1
```

---

**Example Invalid Usage 2:**

```
input_number = "4007-6000-0000"
```

**Output:**

```
The entered credit number is not valid. Error code: 3
```

---

**Example Valid Usage:**

```
input_number = "4002-0060-0000"
```

**Output:**

```
The entered credit number is valid.
```

Comment: Could u plz explain  elif int(number_str[0:2]) + int(number_str[7:9]) != 100:
        return 4 for me, i dnt get it

Comment: `number_str[0:2]` gets the substring from the 0th character (inclusive) to the 2nd character (exclusive) i.e. the 1st character and therefore `number_str[0:2]` represents the string of the first two characters. Similarly `number_str[7:9]` represents the string containing the 7th and 8th numbers (remember there is `-` characters in the string you need to account for.) For more info see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3